# How to get Active visitors,Sessions,page views and bounces Based on devices(Desktop, Mobile and app)

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Am using google api to get Active visitors,Sessions,page views and bounces(Not based on devices);
my code is like this:

```
<?php

$strRadioType = "RealTime";
//$strRadioType = $_GET['rdReportType'];
if($strRadioType != "RealTime"){
    $dtFromFormat = $_GET['dtFromDate'];
    $dtToFormat = $_GET['dtToDate']; 
}else{
    $dtFromFormat = date("Y-m-d");
    $dtToFormat = date("Y-m-d");
}
set_include_path('src/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once "Google/Client.php";
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';
$CLIENT_ID = '*******';
$CLIENT_EMAIL = '****@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';
$KEY_FILE = 'key.p12';
$GA_VIEW_ID = 'ga:66379307';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($CLIENT_ID);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(
    new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $CLIENT_EMAIL,
        array($SCOPE),
        file_get_contents($KEY_FILE)
    )
 );

  $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
  try {
    if($strRadioType == "RealTime"){
        $result1 = $service->data_realtime->get(
            $GA_VIEW_ID,
            'rt:activeVisitors' 
        );
    }
    $result = $service->data_ga->get(
        $GA_VIEW_ID,
         $dtFromFormat,
         $dtToFormat,
        'ga:pageViews'
    );

    $result2 = $service->data_ga->get(
        $GA_VIEW_ID,
         $dtFromFormat,
         $dtToFormat,
        'ga:bounces'
    );

    $result3 = $service->data_ga->get(
        $GA_VIEW_ID,
         $dtFromFormat,
         $dtToFormat,
        'ga:sessions'
    );
    echo "<table border='1' style='font-size:12px;'>";
    if($strRadioType == "RealTime"){
        echo "<tr><th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>Total Active Visitors</th>";
    }else{
        echo "<tr><th>From Date</th><th>To Date</th>";
    }
    echo "<th>Total Pageviews</th><th>Total Bounce</th><th>Total                    Sessions</th></tr>";
    if($strRadioType == "RealTime"){
        echo "<tr><td>". $dtFromFormat."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$result1->totalsForAllResults['rt:activeVisitors']."</td>";
    }else{
        echo "<tr><td>". $dtFromFormat."</td><td>". $dtToFormat."</td>";
    }
    echo "<td>".$result->totalsForAllResults['ga:pageViews']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$result2->totalsForAllResults['ga:bounces']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$result3->totalsForAllResults['ga:sessions']."</td></tr></table>";
   // echo "Total Device Category : ".$result4-      >totalsForAllResults['rt:deviceCategory']."<br/>";
} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

?>

This code is working fine. But Here am fetching Total data not based on devices(Desk top, Mobile and App).

Am getting output as follows:
[image]

So, finally my concern is need to fetch this data based on devices(Desktop, Mobile and app).

Some one help me out....

Comment: I don't understand the question.   I am not sure what dimension you think desktop moble and app is.    have you considered using https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/platform#rt:deviceCategory?  and why are you making 3 different requests?

Comment: Actually i tried using 'rt:deviceCategory' this(from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/platform#rt:deviceCategory) in the above code but i dint get any result. May be the way i used it is wrong. Let me know how to use 'rt:deviceCategory' this in the above code... @ DaImTo

Comment: probably not last I checked 'rt:deviceCategory' didn't actually return anything.   Realtime api is limited.

Comment: Any way thanks. Let me know if there is any api's to get deviceCategories @DaImTo